# The SqlCeParameter with this name is already contained by this SqlCeParameterCollection. Error

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

In this code I have a button click event. Whenever I click the button first time, the code works fine. But if I click the button other time it throws the error.

My code is

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string itemname = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

    con.Open();

    command.CommandText = "DELETE FROM pricedata WHERE Item=@item";
    command.Connection = con;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item", itemname);

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();                
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: This is the kind of errors that you encounter when using needless global variables. The SqlCeCommand and the SqlCeConnection should be local variables instantiated only when needed and disposed after usage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you try to add your `@item` parameter second time to your command and that's why you get an error as;

> Hey! Your command has *already* this named parameter. You can't add the
>   same named parameter to your command. That's meaningless.

You can use `.Clear()` method to clear your parameters of your command before you execute it for example.

```
command.Parameters.Clear();
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item", itemname);
```

And of course, don't use `AddWithValue` method. [It *may* generate unexpected results sometimes](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Use `.Add()` overloads to specify your parameter type and size. Would be better to use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispsoe your `SqlCeConnection` and `SqlCeCommand` automatically instead of calling `Close` or `Dispose` methods manually. And local connections are always preferable. It's best to open and close the connections as close as possible to *their use*. ADO.NET will do [connection pooling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) so that this will not be expensive at all.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(var con = new SqlCeConnection(conString))
    using(var command = con.CreateCommand())
    {
       command.CommandText = "DELETE FROM pricedata WHERE Item = @item";
       command.Parameters.Clear();
       command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item", comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
       con.Open();
       command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }                 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your connection object is external, global to this method. Just shorten its lifetime, make it local:

```
conn.Open();

command = new SqlCeCommand();
command.Connection = conn; 

...

command.Dispose();
```